# Modal Pop up window on Rails Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

In my customer index view if I click on delete customer button, the following actions take place in my Customers controller delete method.

**Customers_controller.rb**

class CustomersController < ApplicationController
.
.

```
def destroy
    if Customerarticle.where(author_id: params[:id]).count > 0
      #####I need the logic here to display a modal window on my index page of customers here#####
    else
      Customer.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "Customer deleted"
      # debugger
      redirect_to customers_path
  end
```

So based on my condition if it's true means customer can't be deleted, and that message to be displayed in a modal pop up window on Customers index page itself, how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you issue an *ajax* request when the button was clicked and make it redirect to your destroy action. Then, within the controller do your logic and simply return a true/false (or whatever else you need) and use it in your JS callback.

For example:

In your view.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#delete_button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/URL/TO/CONTROLLER",
      data: { id: someID},
      success: function(result){
        if(result == true) {
          // Do something
        } else {
          window.location.replace(result);
        }
    }});
  });
});
```

In your controller:

```
def destroy
    if Customerarticle.where(author_id: params[:id]).count > 0
      return true
    else
      Customer.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "Customer deleted"
      return customers_path
    end
end
```

This should work just fine. Remember, it definitely needs some re-work and adjustments :)